# Should there be a comma before 'even'?

Tags: sentence-construction, commas

> "He who makes amends and does so without hesitation, his reputation will be grand, even among his enemies."

I don't understand where the comma splice is? "He who makes amends and does so without hesitation" is not independent. @stangdon @FumbleFingers

Comment: I'd vote for *having a comma*.

Comment: I'd keep the comma too !

Comment: On a different note, wouldn't _'amoungst'_ be a better word instead of _'amoung'_ ?

Comment: @VarunKN - I think you mean "amongst", not "amoungst".

Comment: I would actually lose the comma, because the "even among his enemies" part isn't, in my opinion, actually a parenthetical or an aside as much as it is the real point of the saying.  However, my bigger concern is that the sentence features a [comma splice](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/engagement/2/1/34/), because "his reputation will be grand" is an independent clause.  It would be more grammatical and fluent to say "He who makes amends and does so without hesitation will have a grand reputation..."

Comment: Commas can be used to indicate a pause in speech. The degree to which that is considered acceptable grammar will depend highly on who is deciding what is acceptable. In this, I'd say the second comma is serving that role primarily. It draws attention to the "even".

Answer (score 3):

The entire sentence isn't really an idiomatic construction anyway (it's an unusual syntax almost exclusively reserved for poetic / aphoristic "maxims, declarations"). Plus it would always look "strange" to most native speakers, because reputations are invariably ***great***, not ***grand***.

But the final comma is entirely a stylistic choice, as can be shown by the fact that it's perfectly okay to speak the line with/without a significant pause at that point (which is ***all*** the comma represents here).